# syntax error in sql statement: vba access

Tags: ms-access, vba

This code won't execute without a `syntax error` error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub cboInvFindVendorName_AfterUpdate()

Me.cboInvFindDate.RowSource = "SELECT [InvoiceDate] FROM tblInvoices " & _
WHERE [vendorID] = " & Nz(me.cboInvFindVendorname) ORDER by [InvoiceDate]"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the previous answers have incorrect quotations around the `nz()` function. also, it appears by the name, that the field is combobox, and it may be more appropriate to refer to its exact column, I went with column zero as this is usually the bound column of the key. I don't think referring to the column is a requirement but I think just makes sure.

```
Me.cboInvFindDate.RowSource = "SELECT [InvoiceDate] FROM tblInvoices " & _
    "WHERE [vendorID] = " & Nz(Me.cboInvFindVendorname.column(0), 0) & " ORDER BY [InvoiceDate]"
```

Comment: This code got rid of the error message.  I put in the zero for the bound column, just to be sure.  Many thanks, Liam!

Answer (score 0):

Try without the '&' after the 'FROM tblInvoices', like so:

```
Private Sub cboInvFindVendorName_AfterUpdate()

Me.cboInvFindDate.RowSource = "SELECT [InvoiceDate] FROM tblInvoices
WHERE [vendorID] = " & Nz(me.cboInvFindVendorname) ORDER by [InvoiceDate]"

End Sub
```

Here's an example of VBA Access SQL syntax I found:

```
 SELECT tblStaff.[Firstname], tblStaff.[Lastname] FROM tblStaff WHERE tblStaff.[Office]="Paris”;
```

**Final Code**

```
Private Sub cboInvFindVendorName_AfterUpdate()

Me.cboInvFindDate.RowSource = "SELECT tblInvoices.[InvoiceDate] FROM tblInvoices
WHERE tblInvoices.[vendorID] = " & Nz(me.cboInvFindVendorname) ORDER by [InvoiceDate]"
```

End Sub

Hope this helps,

Sohail

Answer (score 0):

You missed a quote and a zero:

```
Me.cboInvFindDate.RowSource = "SELECT [InvoiceDate] FROM tblInvoices " & _
"WHERE [vendorID] = " & Nz(Me.cboInvFindVendorname, 0) & " ORDER BY [InvoiceDate]"
```